# Putting iterable in input prompt

Tags: python, loops, input, arguments

I'd like to prompt for a number of points(N), then prompt for the x,y co-ordinates of those points based on N.

I'm going for something like this:

```
inp1 = int(input("enter number of points: "))
for i in range(1,inp1+1):
    inp2 = input("input x co-ord of point i: ")
```

Of course, i is within the quotes and is just showing "i" in the input prompt. I've tried doing ("prompt", i) but input only takes 1 argument.

How can I get around this? Thanks

Comment: It's time to learn [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Thanks. I actually looked at this already but I struggle to understand the python notes. I'm about 10 hours of coding into python and I've not done programming before.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main() :
    inp1 = int(input("enter number of points: "))
    for i in range(1,inp1+1):
        inp2 = input("input x co-ord of point "+str(i) +" : ")

main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfectly. I tried +i earlier but didn't think to do str(i). I'll know for next time! Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @GarryStewart: or using string formatting: `input("input x co-ord of point {i}: ".format(i=i))`